# Office365 Unified API Events endpoint not working

Tags: office365, office365-apps, office365api, office365-restapi

It seems that the following path:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<userId>/Events
```

does not work anymore.

It breaks with an Internal Server Error(500) with the following message:

> "Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject to
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deployment is complete the endpoint is returning expected information with the updated schema

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the inconvenience.  Due to breaking changes being rolled out to Beta endpoint, as described in this [blog post](http://dev.office.com/blogs/Update-3-on-Office-365-Unified-API),  you are seeing /Events fail.  some of the changes include datetime property renamed from dateTimeX to XDateTime, and new format for timezones and reminder info.  As soon as our deployment is complete, the API should work fine for you.

Comment: Thanks Venkat. 
You mean the .NET library used in the server side right?
If you are talking about the client side, I did not mention the usage of any library, its a pure GET request that complies with the RESTFUL service of yours

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. The root cause is still the breaking changes I mentioned.  But I was assuming you were using a client library, and not a library used server side.  We certainly need to have a better error message returned to you in this case.  Have updated my answer.